# Include multiple pub keys in a x509v3-cert

Tags: x.509

Is it possible to include multiple public keys and the issuer's public key in one x509v3-certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

X509v3 as per [RFC 5280, section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) only allows a single `subjectPublicKeyInfo` field.

And this is the field that contains the public key. So no, you only get one.

### MPK proposal didn't make it.

It seems that there was a proposal to introduce a *[Multiple-Public-Key (MPK) Certificate Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-lin-mpk-app-00)* in 2001, but it never led anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Very shortly: it's not possible with the standard certificate fields, however you can always define your own certificate extension:

> ```
>  Extension  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
>      extnID      OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
>      critical    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
>      extnValue   OCTET STRING
>                  -- contains the DER encoding of an ASN.1 value
>                  -- corresponding to the extension type identified
>                  -- by extnID
>  }
> ```

So you have to think up your own object identifier (OID) and then you can put anything in the OCTET STRING which is just a byte array. In the case of an issuer public key you could include the full `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` field from the corresponding certificate. Of course, it probably would only allow specific software to find the public key in there. In this case a *non-critical* extension would be most logical (`critical = FALSE`).

Answer (score -1):

According to [RFC 2459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459), the public key is encoded as a sequence, which means that more than one should be possible. I don't think it is common, and I don't know if all software would handle such a certificate correctly.

The issuer's public key must be in a separate certificate, because it doesn't match your subject name. If the certificate is encoded in PEM format, you can often simply concatenate your own certificate, and the issuer's, into a single file.

Comment: It is a `SEQUENCE`, not a `SEQUENCE OF`. So it is not "naturally" extensible to multiple public keys. The `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure contains an `AlgorithmIdentifier` that identifies the algorithm, then the public key value as a `BIT STRING`. If you want to include several keys, you should define a _new_ identifier for an algorithm that says "several keys", then a _new_ syntax for the value that will include the keys. Neither of this is currently defined, so it has zero chance of being already supported.

Comment: @Kevin Keane Sorry, Thomas and Stackz are right... I made the same mistake as you...^^